# Variables y Tablas temporales en SQL, ejercicio

Tags: mysql, sql

Se me presentó este ejercicio:

Mostrar los alumnos que se hayan inscripto a más cursos que Antoine de Saint-Exupery. Mostrar todos los datos de los alumnos, la cantidad de cursos a la que se inscribió y cuantas veces más que Juan Perez.

Las tablas presentes son:

**Alumnos**

```
  `dni` 
  `nombre` 
  `apellido`
  `tel` 
  `email`
  `direccion`
```

**Inscripciones**

```
  `nom_plan` 
  `nro_curso`
  `dni` 
  `fecha_inscripcion`
```

**Cursos**

```
  `nom_plan` 
  `nro_curso`
  `fecha_ini` 
  `fecha_fin`
  `salon` 
  `cupo`
```

Lo que yo hice es esto:

```
select alu.`dni`, alu.`nombre`, alu.`apellido`, alu.`direccion`, alu.`email`,
alu.`tel`, count(*)
from alumnos alu
inner join inscripciones insc
on alu.`dni` = insc.`dni`
inner join cursos cur
on cur.`nro_curso` = insc.`nro_curso`
group by 1
```

Y lo que me faltaria es la parte de la subconsulta que la haria con un HAVING como tambien el otro count donde se muestran cuantas veces mas que Juan Perez se inscribieron, pero me dicen que lo haga con variables o tablas temporales. Y la verdad no entiendo como hacerlo, alguien que me ayude? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sería:

1. Declarar una variable de tipo entero, crear una consulta que te permita obtener el número de inscripciones de Juan Perez, y asignar este valor a la variable, por ejemplo:

`select @numero_inscripciones_juan_perez := count(*)`

2. En la consulta que ya tienes podrías incluir unicamente la columna dni y su count:

`select alu.'dni', count(alu.'dni') as numero_inscripciones`

Luego agregar la clausula having, comparar que el número de inscripciones de los estudiantes sea mayor que el valor de la variable:

`having count(alu.'dni') > @numero_inscripciones_juan_perez`

Investiga como crear una tabla temporal y llenarla con los datos de esta consulta.

3. Ya tienes los estudiantes que se han inscrito más veces que Juan Perez, ya solo tienes que mostrar el número de veces extra:

`select dni, numero_inscripciones, numero_inscripciones-@numero_inscripciones_juan_perez
 from tabla_temporal`

Comment: Muchas gracias @JYass